# Replace the last occurrence of a word in a string - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem where I need to replace the last occurrence of a word in a string.

**Situation:** I am given a string which is in this format:

```
string filePath ="F:/jan11/MFrame/Templates/feb11";
```

I then replace `TnaName` like this:

```
filePath = filePath.Replace(TnaName, ""); // feb11 is TnaName
```

This works, but I have a problem when `TnaName` is the same as my `folder name`. When this happens I end up getting a string like this:

```
F:/feb11/MFrame/Templates/feb11
```

Now it has replaced both occurrences of `TnaName` with `feb11`. Is there a way that I can replace only the last occurrence of the word in my string?

**Note: `feb11` is `TnaName` which comes from another process - that's not a problem.**

Comment: Is your only goal to replace the last part of the path? (that is, from `/` onwards?)

Comment: No not a last part  repalce only last `TnaName` there is more in path but i generate only sample for question.Thanks.

Comment: Is this string always a path to something? Consider to use System.IO.Path class if it is.

Comment: Yes  string always a path to something.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Here is the function to replace the last occurrence of a `string`

```cs
public static string ReplaceLastOccurrence(string source, string find, string replace)
{
    int place = source.LastIndexOf(find);
    
    if (place == -1)
       return source;
    
    return source.Remove(place, find.Length).Insert(place, replace);
}
```

- `source` is the string on which you want to do the operation.
- `find` is the string that you want to replace.
- `replace` is the string that you want to replace it with.

Comment: beware, maybe there is no match (i.e. `Place == -1`)

Comment: It's probably more logical to return source than empty string in case match not found.

Comment: Add _this_ between ( and string Source as in: `public static string ReplaceLastOccurance(this string Source...` and you have nifty extension method that you can use to replace the last occurrence of string for any string.

Comment: And since it's *not* an Extension Method, it should have the following check at the beginning:

" if (source == null)
 {
  return source;
 }
"

Comment: I made a extension method with this code and it works very well

Answer (score 12):

Use `string.LastIndexOf()` to find the index of the last occurrence of the string and then use substring to look for your solution.

Answer (score 10):

You have to do the replace manually:

```
int i = filePath.LastIndexOf(TnaName);
if (i >= 0)
    filePath = filePath.Substring(0, i) + filePath.Substring(i + TnaName.Length);
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why Regex can't be used:

```cs
public static string RegexReplace(this string source, string pattern, string replacement)
{
  return Regex.Replace(source,pattern, replacement);
}

public static string ReplaceEnd(this string source, string value, string replacement)
{
  return RegexReplace(source, $"{value}$", replacement);
}

public static string RemoveEnd(this string source, string value)
{
  return ReplaceEnd(source, value, string.Empty);
}
```

Usage:

```cs
string filePath ="F:/feb11/MFrame/Templates/feb11";
filePath = filePath.RemoveEnd("feb11"); // F:/feb11/MFrame/Templates/
filePath = filePath.ReplaceEnd("feb11","jan11"); // F:/feb11/MFrame/Templates/jan11
```

Comment: You should Regex.Escape() value.

Comment: You mean, `return Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(source),pattern, replacement);`?

Comment: Suppose someone calls ReplaceEnd("(foobar)", ")", "thenewend"). Your function will throw, because ")$" is an invalid regex. This would work: return RegexReplace(source, Regex.Escape(value)+"$", replacement); Same story for your RemoveEnd.

Comment: @jcox, I couldn't figure out how to avoid double-escaping, b/c each function is public so we have multiple potential call paths. In my case I wasn't using it for special characters, but I do see your point.

Comment: @toddmo I would have ReplaceEnd and RemoveEnd call Regex.Replace directly. Kinda off-topic, though; I'd just like people to be aware that injecting user input into a regex pattern can be tricky. Similar to injecting input into XML or SQL -- there needs to be some escape mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

The solution can be implemented even more simple with a single line:

```
 static string ReplaceLastOccurrence(string str, string toReplace, string replacement)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(str, $@"^(.*){Regex.Escape(toReplace)}(.*?)$", $"$1{Regex.Escape(replacement)}$2");
    }
```

Hereby we take advantage of the greediness of the regex asterisk operator. The function is used like this:

```
var s = "F:/feb11/MFrame/Templates/feb11";
var tnaName = "feb11";
var r = ReplaceLastOccurrence(s,tnaName, string.Empty);
```

Comment: This will break if `toReplace` is not properly escaped for regex

Comment: You are right. I fixed this by escaping toReplace and replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Path` class from `System.IO` namepace:

```
string filePath = "F:/jan11/MFrame/Templates/feb11";

Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function splits a string where the pattern (word to be replaced) last occurs.
Then it changes the pattern with the replacement string (in the second half of the string).
Finally, it concatenates both string halves back with each other again.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public string ReplaceLastOccurance(string source, string pattern, string replacement)
{
   int splitStartIndex = source.LastIndexOf(pattern, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
   string firstHalf = source.Substring(0, splitStartIndex);
   string secondHalf = source.Substring(splitStartIndex, source.Length - splitStartIndex);
   secondHalf = Regex.Replace(secondHalf, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

   return firstHalf + secondHalf;
}
```