# append word in middle of string

Tags: c#, string

I have the following code:

```
string group = "1,2,3,4,5";
```

And I need to find the last comma in the group (which in this case is between 4 and 5) and replace it with the word "AND". Do I need to use LINQ for this? If so, how?

Comment: Pedantic Note: "append" means "add to the end", so you can't "append something in the middle of something". (I'm referring to the title at the time of writing this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use LINQ, just use `LastIndexOf`

```
string str = "1,2,3,4,5";

int pos = str.LastIndexOf(',');
string result = str.Substring(0, pos) + " and " + str.Substring(pos + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will work, though you might want to add a check if group even contains a comma:

```
string group = "1,2,3,4,5";
int i = group.LastIndexOf(",");
string str = group.Substring(0, i) + " and " + group.Substring(i + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a normal for loop for this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "1,2,3,4,5";

    for (int i=str.Length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (str[i] == ',') {
            str = str.Substring(0, i+1) + " and " + str.Substring(i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

output of the program is

```
1,2,3,4, and 5
```

Comment: I think the OP meant the output to be somewhat like: 1,2,3,4 and 5

Comment: @user5173426 then change statement to ```str.Substring(0, i) + " and " + str.Substring(i + 1);```

Answer (score 0):

[Neat and clean and on point.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825949/replace-the-last-occurrence-of-a-word-in-a-string-c-sharp)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    var res = ReplaceLastOccurrence("1,2,3,4,5", ",", " and ");
     Console.WriteLine(res);
 }
public static string ReplaceLastOccurrence(string Source, string Find, string Replace)
  {
      int place = Source.LastIndexOf(Find);   
      if(place == -1)
        return Source;
       string result = Source.Remove(place, Find.Length).Insert(place, Replace);
        return result;
  }
```

[Fiddle Output:](http://rextester.com/BPSQE31588)

```
1,2,3,4 and 5
```