# remove specific text from middle of string (only first occurrence from end of a string)

Tags: c#, .net, string

I need to remove a specific value from middle of a string and only its first occurrence from end of the string e.g.

Url : `https://something/ABCD/EFGH/IJKL/**ABCD**?id=1234567910`

In above url string I need to replace last "ABCD" with "NEW" as below:

Url : `https://something/ABCD/EFGH/IJKL/**NEW**?id=1234567910`

currently how I'm doing this is

```
using System;  
  
namespace StringReplaceSample  
{  
   public class Program  
    {  
        public static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
        string pageid = "?id=1234567910";//its something i can retrive or get
        
        string example = "https://something/ABCD/EFGH/IJKL/ABCD?id=1234567910";
        String[] breakApart = example.Split('/');
        var exampleTrimmedlastValue =  breakApart[breakApart.Length-1];
        var exampleReplace = example.Replace(exampleTrimmedlastValue,"NEW");
        var exampleTrimmed = exampleReplace+pageid;
        Console.WriteLine("Original string:" +example);
        Console.WriteLine("Trimmed string:"+exampleTrimmed); 
        }  
    }  
}
```

but I don't find this very efficient and its huge can someone suggest any simpler way to do this

Comment: Why not just `.Replace("/ABCD?","/NEW?")` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace the last occurrence of a word in a string - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825949/replace-the-last-occurrence-of-a-word-in-a-string-c-sharp)

Comment: yes using above link i have created created the solution posted as an answer to it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reviewing all you suggestions i have added below code to achieve my desired solution.

```
using System;  
  
namespace StringReplaceSample  
{  
   public class Program  
    {  
        public static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
        string example = "https://something/ABCD/EFGH/IJKL/ABCD?id=1234567910";
        string replaceValue = "ABCD";
        int lastIndex = example.LastIndexOf(replaceValue, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
        example = example.Remove(lastIndex, replaceValue.Length).Insert(lastIndex, "NEW");        
        Console.WriteLine("Original string:" +example); 
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. It will first find position of the string which you need to remove and if it finds it will remove it.

```
public static string ReplaceLastOccurrence(string Source, string Find, string Replace)
{
        int place = Source.LastIndexOf(Find);

        if(place == -1)
           return Source;

        string result = Source.Remove(place, Find.Length).Insert(place, Replace);
        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the thing you want to find and replace is ALWAYS after a slash "/" and before "?id=", then you could just do:

```
string example = "https://something/ABCD/EFGH/IJKL/ABCD?id=1234567910";

string find = "ABCD";
string replaceWith = "NEW";
string exampleTrimmed = example.Replace("/" + find + "?id=", "/" + replaceWith + "?id=");

Console.WriteLine("Original string: " + example);
Console.WriteLine("Trimmed string: "+ exampleTrimmed);
```